# Image with a link in a specific point

Tags: javascript, css, image, jquery-hover

I need to create a website with this kind of function:

I have an image (like a park area), so in different points of this image I must create a div which will do a hover effect and show a textbox with an image (or maybe a link to it).

My main doubt is that I have no idea how can I get certain points of this image to create a div with this hover effect.

Comment: Why not use an image map?  Plenty of free image map makers online to let you define sections of a single image to have different URLs and title text that pops up on hover.  Syntax is like.. `<area shape=rect coords="0,0,175,240" href="index.html" title="will display on the mouse over of the link area"` ...

Comment: @DuaneLortie I can't use it because I'll have different images which aren't related to a street, city, etc. I have to "map" or "tag" this hovers into an image which represents a work station in 3D

Comment: ?  Imagemap has nothing to do with streets or cities, it's a way to take a single image of anything and make different parts clickable to point to different URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below URL's. Hope this may helpful

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/html/imagemaps

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

Comment: yes you can add whatever by using  "HTML mapping" :)

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

you can do with jQuery. Please, firstly look at this [link](http://api.jquery.com/event.pagex/). You can take mouse x and y position on image. Then on x and y position, you can do, what you want.

Comment: Amazing! It works perfectly, but how may I mark a "limit" between each part of the x and y axis to make like a coordinate like a square so it will get this range?