# Map onmouseover with data-toggle tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onmouseover

This is a continuation of this question

[Image with a link in a specific point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601351/image-with-a-link-in-a-specific-point)

I've found the property onmouseover  and I thought really interesting the fact that it may trigger a function with it.

So well, I have to show a tooltip exactly on the top of the map area that I attributed the onmouseover property.

Is there any way I can do this? 
I've been trying to do it but I couldn't show it on top of the area, only separated

this is what I tried:

```
  <area  id="test" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left" shape="rect" href="" onmouseover='' onmouseout='' coords="750,435,540,300">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your map as a `background-image`:

```
#mapcontainer { background-image: url('path/to/map.png'); }
```

Then just align the textarea or input inside the same container:

```
#mapcontainer input[type="text"] { margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 100px; /*change as necessary*/ }
```

A background-image prevents you from having to add a position absolute / z-index combination to the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) will achieve it the layout you're looking for.

I would also suggest you use an element that isn't an input or textarea. Use something like a div instead to make it semantic.

Comment: I'd write that I'm looking for a div on the question, but I thought I'd sound quite crazy haha

Comment: Heh, I just find divs and other non-form elements easier to style. However, this is usually fixed via a reset css.

Comment: I've re-wrote the question, so I guess it's more understandable now